# Unable to update channel config using Fabric SDK Java: field "common.ConfigUpdate.channel_id" contains invalid UTF-8

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-java

**Network setup:**

The network is setup with 1 orderer + 2 organizations with 2 peers each (2 * 2 = 4 peers).

I don't think there's a problem with the network, nor with the crypto materials, the channel config transactions, since I've done similar things using Fabric SDK Go without going into this kind of problem.

**What I have done:**

The error occurs after I created the channel "mychannel", added two peers of the client org to the channel, initialized the channel using Fabric SDK Java and then **tried to update the channel**.

Before I tried to invoke `channel.updateChannelConfiguration()` to apply the config tx file `Org1MSPanchors.tx`, I managed to get the signatures from the admins of both the orgs.

The key lines (the project is written in Kotlin, the following is the Java equivalent):

```
var updateConfig = new UpdateChannelConfiguration(new File("path/to/file.tx"));
// The signatures have been created from the admins of the 2 orgs.
channel.updateChannelConfiguration(updateConfig, signatures);
```

**Logs:**

After the invocation, the program crashed with the following info.

```
Caused by: org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.TransactionException: Channel mychannel, send transaction failed on orderer OrdererClient{id: 4, channel: mychannel, name: orderer.***.com, url: grpcs://localhost:7050}. Reason: Channel mychannel orderer orderer.***.com status returned failure code 400 (BAD_REQUEST) during orderer next
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.OrdererClient.sendTransaction(OrdererClient.java:240) ~[fabric-sdk-java-1.4.13.jar:na]
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Orderer.sendTransaction(Orderer.java:164) ~[fabric-sdk-java-1.4.13.jar:na]
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.sendUpdateChannel(Channel.java:549) ~[fabric-sdk-java-1.4.13.jar:na]
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.updateChannelConfiguration(Channel.java:455) ~[fabric-sdk-java-1.4.13.jar:na]
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.updateChannelConfiguration(Channel.java:412) ~[fabric-sdk-java-1.4.13.jar:na]
    at com.***.util.SDKUtil$Companion.updateChannel(SDKUtil.kt:68) ~[main/:na]
    at com.***.***Application.configureChannel(FjstApplication.kt:76) ~[main/:na]
    at com.***.***Application.access$configureChannel(FjstApplication.kt:19) ~[main/:na]
    at com.***.***Application$commandLineRunner$2.run(FjstApplication.kt:54) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:804) [spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.TransactionException: Channel mychannel orderer orderer.***.com status returned failure code 400 (BAD_REQUEST) during orderer next
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.OrdererClient$1.onNext(OrdererClient.java:186) ~[fabric-sdk-java-1.4.13.jar:na]
```

And the docker logs of `orderer.***.com`:

```
2020-12-14 09:14:48.443 UTC [orderer.commmon.multichannel] newChain -> INFO 00b Created and starting new chain mychannel
2020-12-14 09:14:48.451 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 00c streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=192.168.128.1:35988 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=60.307408ms
2020-12-14 09:15:01.201 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 00d streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=192.168.128.1:35988 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=1.770753ms
2020-12-14 09:15:01.208 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] ProcessMessage -> WARN 00e [channel: mychannel] Rejecting broadcast of config message from 192.168.128.1:35988 because of error: error applying config update to existing channel 'mychannel': error authorizing update: proto: field "common.ConfigUpdate.channel_id" contains invalid UTF-8
2020-12-14 09:15:01.208 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 00f streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Broadcast grpc.peer_address=192.168.128.1:35988 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=349.969µs
```

**The config and network files:**

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aj_rPvkyS8y8gtsXEaKBXD1riM12CQ?e=jkMeYn

**Please help:**

If a solution is not obvious, could you please tell me what the possible causes are?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you upload the configuration file too?

Comment: @myeongkilkim Sure! Files uploaded.

Comment: JDK code also needs to be checked.
The error that currently occurs is because the channel_id item received by the Orderer through gRPC does not exist as "".
At the configuration side for JDK or *.tx file or tx file creation, trying to find the part that is not specified for the channel name. Can you give a place to declare the channel part of JDK code?

Comment: @myeongkilkim It might be possible to set the ID, but obviously it's not designed to be set manually in SDK. The .tx file is loaded into an `UpdateChannelConfiguration` object and the object only two significant functions: `updateChannelConfigurationAsBytes()` and `setUpdateChannelConfiguration()`. It might be possible to set the channel ID / name, but I don't know how to read the bytes. Besides, in SDK Go, applying the anchor peer .tx file is just as simple as applying the channel creation .tx file. No ID needs to be set.

Comment: Currently, your error occurred while interpreting the gRPC payload in the orderer.
Specifically, it occurred in the process of obtaining `ChnnelID` in the process of `ProcessConfigUpdateMsg` function on `fabric/orderer/common/msgprocessor/systemchannel.go`, and this process is connected by `ChannelHeader` function on `ChannelID` function of `hyperledger/fabric/protoutil/commonutils.go`, and payload This is an error that occurred in protobuf during unmarshaling.

Comment: In other words, as mentioned 2days ago, it was reported that the value of the `channel_id` item received from gRPC could not be interpreted.
In the end, what the channel_id item value is set to cannot be checked in the orderer, and must be checked in the JDK.

Comment: I am not curious about the `UpdateChannelConfiguration` class. The command you actually run is the `updateChannelConfiguration` method of the `channel` class. Naturally, there must be information related to `channel_id(name)` in the `channel` class. I am curious about how the information is.

Comment: So in the end, I will ask you again. Can you give a place to declare the channel part of JDK code?

Comment: Well, as for the ID information, the `Channel` class doesn't literally hold an ID field. In debug mode, I can tell the ID is `3` from its `toString()` method, or `Channel{id: 3, name: mychannel}` to be specific. I can only change the value in debug mode. And sorry I don't quite understand what you mean by saying "declare the channel part of JDK code". The channel was created using `client.newChannel()` method with `channel.tx` and that's it. I didn't declare it explicitly anywhere else.

Comment: `channel = client.newChannel(<your_channel_name>);` Could you test it by changing it with this code? in constructor declaration part, it is set when channel_name is entered as an input parameter. If the error occurs because channel_name arrived empty, it will be resolved.